# Ad Manager, invalid traffic and click

Tags: android, ios, admob, google-ad-manager

I have an app on both iOS and android platforms.
I use **Ad Manager SDK** for displaying ads. Everything is ok for android app. But there is something wrong for iOS app.

Google says "***invalid traffic and click***".

**Interstitial** ads' impressions and clicks are well. But **banner type** ads don't count clicks. They don't earn money.

I did everything what google documents say.

I tried the following methods:

- I improved the viewability for ads. Every ad is requested on time.
- I used Charles Session too. There is no duplicate or spam requests.
- Then I created new adIDs. It works well just a couple of day. Then again same problem occurs.

Google says:
"**Non-Human Traffic**: Traffic or clicks generated via robots, spiders or crawlers are filtered by DFP

**Automated ad clicking**: The instances include: multiple clicks fired and clicks fired without user interactions are marked as malicious activity in the system"
in email.

They dont say anything else. My account is not blocked.
How can I avoid invalid traffic and bot clicks? Is there anything else I must do?

I use:

1. pod 'GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK'
2. pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'

for ads.

Comment: Make sure you re not using bots to click your own or tell other people to do

Comment: i am pretty sure there is no bot click. I log clicks on my server too. there is no suspicious events. I have 500K active users. no need to tell people to click.

Comment: if i m not wrong , you have the possibility to check your click traffic events i guess

Comment: @usman have you got any solution?

Comment: @uzman did you fix your problem cuz I have it also for no reason only for banner

Comment: @AhmedSafadi there is no solution. I think Google puts the app in a blacklist (by the way, they say there is no blacklist).  Maybe you can solve it by contacting google. It is up to Google. :(

Comment: @uzman as they respond, they didn't respond to emails, did you try to use another AdMob account?

Comment: @AhmedSafadi, yes I tried another account. At first it counts the clicks, after a few hours later google deletes the clicks again.

Comment: @uzman that mean they blacklist us, did you try another payment company like Facebook ads

Comment: @AhmedSafadi yes, I tried other mediations (companies) too. Nothing changed.

Comment: :(, then I guess we have to change the admob